# ¿Por qué esta consulta solo devuelve una fila?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código php pero sólo me devuelve una fila, no sé por qué será la tabla tiene 70 filas y la consulta pide entre dos números, estos números vienen de formulario.

Si pongo 1 y 60  o 13 y 40 o algo que se espera devuelva más de una fila siempre regresa sólo la primera fila en el array `$tables`

```
  require '../conn.php';

  $from = $_POST['from'];
  $to = $_POST['to'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM senders WHERE id BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response->sql = $sql;
    $tables = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

      $table = new stdClass;

      $table->id = $row['id'];
      $table->name = $row['name'];
      $table->work = $row['work'];
      $table->domain = $row['domain'];
      $table->email = $row['email'];
      $table->emailEn = $row['emailEn'];
      $table->date = $row['date'];

      $table->qListDB = implode(" * ",json_decode($row['qListDB']));
      $table->area = $row['area'];
      $table->level = $row['level'];
      $table->phone = $row['phone'];
      $table->nameEn = $row['nameEn'];


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM aplications WHERE ide = '{$row['ide']}'"; 
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $questSolved = [];
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          array_push($questSolved,$row['idUrl']);
          $table->age = $row['age'];
          $table->school = $row['school'];
        }
        $table->questSolved = $questSolved;

      } else {
        $table->age = " - ";
        $table->school = " - ";
        $table->questSolved = " - ";
      }
      array_push($tables,$table);
    }
    $response->state = true;
    $response->tables = $tables;
    echo json_encode($response);
  } else {
    $response->state = false;
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné el problema eran los nombres de las variables, estaba usando los mismo nombres en las dos consultas que tenía

```
<?php 

  require '../conn.php';

  $from = $_POST['from'];
  $to = $_POST['to'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM senders WHERE id BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response->sql = $sql;
    $response->num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $tables = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

      $table = new stdClass;

      $table->id = $row['id'];
      $table->name = $row['name'];
      $table->work = $row['work'];
      $table->domain = $row['domain'];
      $table->email = $row['email'];
      $table->emailEn = $row['emailEn'];
      $table->date = $row['date'];

      $table->qListDB = implode(" * ",json_decode($row['qListDB']));
      $table->area = $row['area'];
      $table->level = $row['level'];
      $table->phone = $row['phone'];
      $table->nameEn = $row['nameEn'];


      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM aplications WHERE ide = '{$row['ide']}'"; 
      $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
        $questSolved = [];
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
          array_push($questSolved,$row2['idUrl']);
          $table->age = $row2['age'];
          $table->school = $row2['school'];
        }
        $table->questSolved = $questSolved;
        array_push($tables,$table);

      } else {
        $table->age = " - ";
        $table->school = " - ";
        $table->questSolved = " - ";
      array_push($tables,$table);

      }
    }
    $response->state = true;
    $response->tables = $tables;
    echo json_encode($response);
  } else {
    $response->state = false;
    echo json_encode($response);
  }

?>
```

Comment: podrias optimizar un poco la consulta, haciendo un join entre las tablas `applications` y `senders`. Con eso solo tendrias que leer cada linea de resultados, en lugar de hacer varias consultas, como haces en tu codigo

Comment: Y podrías usar consultas preparadas ya que actualmente tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.